# Can an extra property be added to a JSON Patch document?

Tags: json, http, patch

I want to add an extra property `label` to a JSON Patch document. 
Is it possible to do that?

I am using C# Web API and I am not getting the `label` property in my JSON.

Could anyone suggest if is there any option there other than altering value to object?

```js
[
  { "op": "replace", "path": "/baz", "value": "boo", "label": "displayName" }
]
```

Comment: Not sure if this is directly relevant (since the question is very unclear, and you provided no code, error messages or clear description of what your actual issue is), but JSON properties must have double-quotes round them, i.e. `"label"` not just `label`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to do that?

You *could*, but it doesn't mean you *should*.

> I am not getting the `label` property in my JSON.

I don't know the API you are using to parse such document, but this behavior seems to be consistent with the [RFC 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902), the document that defines the JSON Patch format (highlight is mine):

> [**4.  Operations**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-4)
>
> Operation objects MUST have exactly one `op` member, whose value indicates the operation to perform.  Its value MUST be one of  `add`, `remove`, `replace`, `move`, `copy`, or `test`; other values are errors.
>
> Additionally, operation objects MUST have exactly one `path` member. [...]
>
> The meanings of other operation object members are defined by operation. **Members that are not explicitly defined for the operation in question MUST be ignored** (i.e., the operation will complete as if the undefined member did not appear in the object).